# Using sharedpref strings as inputs into sendTextMessage

Tags: android, sms

I am creating an app that takes String's input by the user via EditText, puts them into a sharedpreference and then sends an automatic sms when an sms is received, using the strings from the sharedpreference to dictate the phone number and text message that will be automatically sent.

The app works perfectly as long as I hardcode the phone number and the text message to be sent. As soon as I try and put the Strings from the shared preferences into the SendSMS method then the app crashes and I get a debug error "hasUserDataHeader : false"

The below code is the version where i try to take the String from the Name EditText and use it as the message to be sent via the parameter TextMessage (see within the broadcast receiver for this line of code). If i were to replace this with "TextMessage" then it would be fine but obviously this doesn't make the text sent dynamic

Code below:

```
                import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.Spinner;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.app.PendingIntent;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.telephony.SmsManager;
            import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.IntentFilter;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.app.Notification;
            import android.app.NotificationManager;
            import android.content.SharedPreferences;

            public class MainActivity extends Activity {

                int notificationID = 1;
                String[] excuses;
                String excuseSelected;
                IntentFilter intentFilter;
                private SharedPreferences prefs;
                private String prefName = "MyPref";
                private static final String NUMBER_KEY = "number";
                private static final String NAME_KEY = "name";
                private static final String EXCUSE_KEY = "excuse"; 


                private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                        //---gather up all the necessary user input---
                        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String textMessage = (String) prefs.getString(NAME_KEY, "");
                        sendSMS("0403579838", textMessage);             
            //          }
                    }
                };

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    //---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
                    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

                    final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonToggle);

                    excuses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.excuses_array);
                    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerExcuse);
                    final EditText EditTextNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
                    final EditText EditTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);



                        //---Sorting the spinner view out for excuses selection---
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, excuses);

                        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
                        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                        {
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3)
                            {
                                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                                excuseSelected = excuses[index];
                            }

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
                        });

                    //---Setting the button to toggle between on and off---
                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (btn1.getText().equals("Turn on"))                       
                            {
                                btn1.setText("Turn off");
                                //---register the receiver---
                                registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
                                //---get the SharedPreferences object---
                                prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                                //---set the user inputs to prefo's---
                                editor.putString(NUMBER_KEY, EditTextNumber.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString(NAME_KEY, EditTextName.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString(EXCUSE_KEY, excuseSelected);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btn1.setText("Turn on");
                                //---unregister the receiver---
                                unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

                //---sends an SMS message to another device---
                public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
                {
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
                    displayNotification();
                }

                protected void displayNotification()
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
                    i.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
                        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    Notification notif = new Notification(
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                            "SMS has been sent by GirlfriendMinder",
                            System.currentTimeMillis());

                    CharSequence from = "GirlfriendMinder";
                    CharSequence message = "SMS has been sent by GirlfriendMinder";

                    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, pendingIntent);

                    //---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100ms, and then vibrate for 500ms---
                    notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};
                    nm.notify(notificationID, notif);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {
                    //---unregister the receiver---
                    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
                    super.onPause();
                }
            }
```

Comment: from where do u want to fetch the message and the phone number to send the SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
//---Setting the button to toggle between on and off---
                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (btn1.getText().equals("Turn on"))                       
                            {
                                btn1.setText("Turn off");
                                //---register the receiver---
                                registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
                                //---get the SharedPreferences object---
                                prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                                //---set the user inputs to prefo's---
                                editor.putString(NUMBER_KEY, EditTextNumber.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString(NAME_KEY, EditTextName.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString(EXCUSE_KEY, excuseSelected);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btn1.setText("Turn on");
                                //---unregister the receiver---
                                unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
```

below:

```
editor.putString(EXCUSE_KEY, excuseSelected);
```

add

```
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for textMessage.

However, if I try and do the same and make the phonenumber dynamic, by using say 

String phoneNumber = (String) prefs.getString(NUMBER_KEY, "");
sendSMS(phoneNumber, textMessage);

Then I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it should not happen, once your commit your object of SharedPreference.Editor it is stored in preference and you will get all the data that you stored it preference.

Comment: I think the issue is with the variable type of PhoneNumber -> When the user inputs "0400111111" instead of 0401111111 then it works. I will build in some extra code to make sure the number is converted to a String.

Thanks for your help with the SharedPreferences Mohit.